# Проблема с отображением значения через компонент v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify

Небольшая проблемка с автокомплитом из Vuetify.

Дело в том, что если в переменную route.city записать какое-то значение другим методом, автокомплит его не отображает.

То есть, например, при создании заказа через автокомплит я записываю значение и все норм, но при апдейте (открыв созданный заказ), я не могу отобразить имеющее значение в автокомплите.

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model='route.city'
    label='Город'
    :items='route.cities'
    item-text='name'
    item-value='uuid'
    @input.native='loadCities'
    @change.native='loadCities'
    return-object
    cache-items
    hide-no-data
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Так `route.city` это часть объекта `route` который вы должны передать сами он в автокомплиту не имеет значения

Comment: Просто если я тот же `route.city` привязываю к любому инпуту то они синхронно меняются. А как правильно передать автокомплиту значение?

Comment: Так у вас должны быть для каждого input своя переменная а автокомтлит в зависимости от него меняет данные

Comment: Они конечно есть. Без них бы вообще ничего не работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример рабочий с [v-autoselect](https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/mvvPqG?editors=1010) 
Обращаю Ваше внимание что в **первой кнопке передается цифра во второй цифра как текст**, что влияет на автоселект. Поэтому если вы работаете с данными полученными из базы данных, нужно задать задавать вашей переменной текст а не цифру как id.

```
this.item.city = 2;
```

Это совсем не тоже что и

```
this.item.city = '2';
```

Поэтому в вашем коде, проверьте при задании переменной `route.city` что именно у вас в `route.cities`

Comment: С типом проблем нет. У меня и в city и в cities объекты с одинаковыми полями. Проблема в том, что у меня cities подтягивается по запросу и на момент загрузки страницы их нет. И v-autocomplete не отображает значение которое записано в city, так как cities еще пуст.

Comment: Ну так в чем вопрос, если объект пуст он и не показывает ничего

Comment: route.city - не пуст, в нем объект с одним городом. Но он не отображается пока я в route.cities не запишу массив содержайщий этот объект.

Comment: так у вас в route.city id города а не его название, если есть и то и то, то запуште в route.cities

Comment: Спасибо! Небольшой костыль конечно, но на данный момент то, что надо!

Comment: Да это не костыль а решение, других вариантов если без запроса к таблице нет. Рад был помочь.  Для меня тоже было интересно узнать что он по разному отработает sting or number